# ODE with variable coefficient raise to $\beta$. Where $\beta$ is a Real Number.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a difficulty solving this second order linear ODE with a variable coefficient.
Below is the equation:

> $$x^\beta\,y'' - \beta\,x^{\beta-1}y' - \gamma\,y = 0 $$

With the following boundary conditions $ y(0) = 0 $ and $y(L) = 0$. 
Where $ \gamma $ is a constant.
I have employed the series method of solution, the Frobenius method to be precise. I also tried to transform the equation to a Bessel kind or something more familiar, but I have been unsuccessful. I tried the Sturm-Liouville approach for solving Second ODE.

Comment: One can wrangle this into the form of a modified Bessel equation with a couple of substitutions. I'm not sure if that's quite what you want, but for a general $\beta$, one can't do any better.

Comment: Actually am looking at a general case of $\beta$ hmmmmm

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$\xi=\int\frac{1}{x^{\beta/2}}dx=\frac{1}{(1-\beta/2)x^{\beta/2-1}}$$
the equation becomes
$$\xi\frac{d^{2}}{d\xi^{2}}y(\xi)-\frac{3\beta}{2-\beta}\frac{d}{d\xi}y(\xi)-\gamma\xi{y(\xi)}=0$$
And the solution is
$$y(\xi)=c_{1}\xi^{\frac{1+\beta}{2-\beta}}J_{\frac{\beta+1}{\beta-2}}(-i\sqrt{\gamma}\xi)+c_{2}\xi^{\frac{1+\beta}{2-\beta}}Y_{\frac{\beta+1}{\beta-2}}(-i\sqrt{\gamma}\xi)$$